# Работа с цветовыми схемами в Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Дано:

1. Схема регионов - файл с изображением из секторов разного цвета и, возможно,  прозрачности.
2. Список регионов текстовый файл с названиями и координатами регионов на схеме.
3. Карта высот - содержит чёрно-белую цветовую схему, задающую высоту над уровнем моря (чёрный - Марианская впадина, серый - ноль, белый - Эверест).
4. Lazarus

Задача: Вывести на экран карту, сгенерированную на основе этих данных, с разграниченными и подписанными регионами.

Вопросы:

1. Какой формат изображений лучше использовать для каждой из схем и почему?
2. Как получить цвет/прозрачность пикселя по известным координатам?

Comment: по поводу второго вопроса: [BGRABitmap](http://wiki.freepascal.org/BGRABitmap)

Answer (score 1):

1а. Любой с поддержкой прозрачности, который вам будет удобно загружать и обрабатывать.
1б. Любой, который вам будет удобно загружать и обрабатывать.
2. Приводите координаты к локальным для картинки и берете соответствующий пиксель (или интерполируете).